# Как добавить поле переключателя в профиль пользователя?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, button, фильтры

Есть сайт на wordpress, хочу добавить в профиль пользователя возможность выбора пола (мужской/женский) с помощью переключателя `radiobutton`. Прописываю в файле `functions.php` фильтр

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'my_user_gender');

function my_user_gender($user_contactmethods){
  $user_contactmethods['gender'] = 'Пол';
  return $user_contactmethods;
}
```

Однако в профиле получаю стандартное поле ввода напротив надписи "Пол". Как сделать это поле в виде переключателя?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать это, используя плагин Advanced Custom Posts[image: скрин]